# For loop to rename .jpg files through batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I want to rename a series of .jpg but i want to append the string at the end of file name. Please help me how can I achive this as I am new to batch file coding.

**Series of jpg files** - 
CurDt_S1, CurDt_S2, CurDt_S3 etc.. uptill S20.

**I want to replace CurDt_S1 with CurDt_1_S1 as -** 
CurDt_1_S1, CurDt_1_S2, CurDt_1_S3 uptill S20.

**Here is the code I am using -**

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set str=_1
    for %%a in (CurDt_S*.jpg) do (
        set oldName=%%a
        set newName=oldname+str
            call :Action
        echo.
        echo back in For loop
    )
    echo.
    echo For loop completed
    echo !oldName!
    echo !newName!
    endlocal
    goto:eof

    :Action
    echo.
    echo start of Action loop
    echo !oldName!
    echo !newName!
    ren "!oldName!" "!newName!"
    echo end of Action loop
```

Thanks,
Sneha

Comment: Proper tagging(language used) will get you help faster..

Comment: Thank you All. Simplest way is working for me. But now, I want to do renaming for all files. Example - CurDt_S1 wud become CurDt_1_S1,CurDt_1_S1 wud become CurDt_2_S1,etc, and S* values wud vary from 1 to 20. I am stuck with for loop part highlighted in bold.
set i=1
**for %%f in ("C:\Users\341256\Documents\batchfile\CurDt_3_S*.jpg") do call :renameit "%%f"**
goto done
pause
:renameit
ren CurDt_3_S%i%.jpg CurDt_4_S%i%.jpg
ren CurDt_2_S%i%.jpg CurDt_3_S%i%.jpg
ren CurDt_1_S%i%.jpg CurDt_2_S%i%.jpg
ren CurDt_S%i%.jpg CurDt_1_S%i%.jpg
set /A i+=1
:done
pause

Comment: Can anyone pls suggest if the code I am using is correct and good to usE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the **SIMPLEST way** to achieve this by using **BATCH in simplest way.**

By Using following code -

```
del CurDt_5_S*
ren CurDt_4_S* CurDt_5_S*
ren CurDt_3_S* CurDt_4_S*
ren CurDt_2_S* CurDt_3_S*
ren CurDt_1_S* CurDt_2_S*
```

I tested it and its working. :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest way I can think of:

```
@echo off
set i=1
for %%f in (CurDt_S*.jpg) do call :renameit "%%f"
goto done

:renameit
ren CurDt_S%i%.jpg CurDt_1_S%i%.jpg

set /A i+=1
:done
```

It assumes the batch files are located in the same directory as the jpg files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /L %%x in (1,1,20) do ECHO ren CurDt_S%%x.jpg CurDt_1_S%%x.jpg
```

should work for you.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%f in ("c:\somewhere\CurDt_*.jpg") do (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%g in ("%%~nf") do echo ren "%%~ff" "%%~g_1_%%~h%%~xf"
)
```

For each of the indicated files, split the name of the file using the first underscore as delimiter to get the two parts, and rename the file to the the first token + `_1_` + second token + file extension.

Result is only echoed to console. If output is correct, remove `echo` command to rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code to rename the files. Basically, it would be as follows -
CurDt_S1 will be renamed as CurDt_1_S1 uptill S20,
CurDt_1_S1 to CurDt_2_S1 uptill S20,
CurDt_2_S1 to CurDt_3_S1 uptill S20,
CurDt_3_S1 to CurDt_4_S1 uptill S20,
and CurDt_4_S1 files will be archived to a diff folder.

Code is as follows-

set i=1
            for %%f in ("C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_4_S*.jpg") do call :currentdate4 "%%f"
            for %%f in ("C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_3_S*.jpg") do call :currentdate3 "%%f"
            for %%f in ("C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_2_S*.jpg") do call :currentdate2 "%%f"
            for %%f in ("C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_1_S*.jpg") do call :currentdate1 "%%f"
            for %%f in ("C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_S*.jpg") do call :currentdate "%%f" 
            goto done
            exit

```
        :currentdate4
            if exist C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_4_S*.jpg (
            rem move C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_4_S*.jpg C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\Archive
            echo moved current_date-4 files )       

        :currentdate3
        if exist C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_3_S*.jpg (
            ren CurDt_3_S%i%.jpg CurDt_4_S%i%.jpg
            echo renamed _3 to _4 )

        :currentdate2
            if exist C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_2_S*.jpg (
            ren CurDt_2_S%i%.jpg CurDt_3_S%i%.jpg
            echo renamed _2 to _3 )

        :currentdate1
        if exist C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_1_S*.jpg (
            ren CurDt_1_S%i%.jpg CurDt_2_S%i%.jpg
            echo renamed _1 to _2 )

        :currentdate
        if exist C:\Users\341256\Desktop\test_batch_files\CurDt_S*.jpg (
            ren CurDt_S%i%.jpg CurDt_1_S%i%.jpg
            echo renamed currdt to _1
            echo complete )

        set /A i+=1
        :done
        pause
```

Please suggest if it is right.

Thanks,
Sneha

Comment: hI ggaans, i am using your suggested to code to rename. I have mentioned it in detail here in abive post. but it is not working for me, it is not renaming all the files but only few files. could you pls help me with this?